# spring default bean scope is singleton , but how it is handled in the actual application?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, scope, singleton

Spring default scope is singleton, but inside the application how it works?? for example with singleton we need to take care of multiple access, which is overhead. Does spring facilitate a way to transform the singleton to regular bean? How it works in the application?

Answer (score 0):

[Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) recommends to use stateless class for singleton Spring beans.

> 1.5.2. The prototype scope
>   As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the
>   singleton scope for stateless beans.

So concurrent access is not an issue.
If you don't follow these recommendations, you will against framework rules and you would have definitively issues in general, as well as concurrency issues.